# how to disable user account control popup for an application by default while creating the setup file

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer

I am having a .msi file which pops up the user account control(UAC) prompt everytime i open it. I need to have it disabled by default. Is there some way in which it can be done in my asp.net or c# code or in windows settings such that it will be disabled by default while the msi is being created. My UAC settings is set to default and i want it to be as it is so that it does not affect the opening of other applications. I only want to disable the UAC prompt for this particular msi file. Could anyone please help me out with this :)

**NOTE:** *I am accessing this msi via shortcut on my desktop. If i right click on it -> properties -> shortcut tab -> advanced -> Run as administrator option is checked and i cant uncheck it. Its disabled.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable UAC from an executable that will defeat the whole purpose of UAC. If your application modifies system level settings/files (as most installers do) UAC prompt will be displayed.